# Unit close disc to prove a matrix algebra identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology

I need to prove that every $3 \times 3$ matrix with real positive entries has one eigenvector with a positive eigenvalue. Now, how do I prove this using the fact that the set $B=\{x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x_i \geq 0 \}$ and also $|x|=1$ is homeomorphic with the closed unit disc?

Answer (score 0):

The strategy to use the [Brouwer fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem) is obvious, right?

So, you're just looking for a continuous function on the closed unit disc in the plane. I'm going to use $\Bbb R^{3+}$ as an ad-hoc notation for $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mid x_i\geq 0\}$. And also I'm using $B:=\{x\in \Bbb R^{3+}\mid |x|=1\}$ as I think you intended.

The hypothesis that the matrix you start with has positive entries says that it is a transformation $T$ that maps $\Bbb R^{3+}$ onto itself. It doesn't map $B$ onto itself: in general vectors get stretched. But we can correct this by composing with the continuous map $n:\Bbb R^{3+}\setminus{\{0\}}\to B$ which just maps $x\mapsto \frac{x}{|x|}$. In summary, $nT:B\to B$ is a continuous map.

Let $h$ be a homeomorphism of $\Bbb R^{3+}$ onto the closed unit disc $D$ in the plane. Then $hnTh^{-1}$ is a continuous function on $D$, so it has a fixed point, say $x$.

Then $hnTh^{-1}(x)=x$ implies $nT(h^{-1}(x))=h^{-1}(x)$, so $nT$ has a fixed point too. Can you see why $h^{-1}(x)$ is an eigenvector? What can you say about its eigenvalue?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I fail to see why $h^{-1}(x)$ is an eigenvector. Would you be able to explain it to me? Certaintly I see something of the form $nT \, U = U$ but is this enough for it to be eigenvector? Also, it seems the eigenvalue is $+1$.

Comment: @marion you're close, but a little off. $nT$ isn't a linear map, so it's not really useful to think about eigenvalues for it. But $n$ Preserves the direction vectors are pointing. You should be using this to think about $U$ and $TU$.

Comment: Then how do I draw any conclusions about the eigenvalues of $nT$?

Comment: @marion The question, and my hints, are about eigenvalues of $T$, not $nT$. You can deduce the eigenvalue must be positive since T preserves the positive octant of 3 space: that's the point. Slow down and think a bit. It's all right here in front of you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! I will try to think about it more.